# Bootstrap submenu items stay open when clicking on other item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
            var current=jQuery(this).next();
            var grandparent=jQuery(this).parent().parent();
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('left-caret')||jQuery(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
            current.toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        jQuery(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
            var root=jQuery(this).closest('.dropdown');
            root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

which addresses this:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu submenu">
    <a class="trigger right-caret">Category Name</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu">
        <li>Subcategory</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is sample code - the subcategory li items are dynamically genetrated in a foreach loop.

Now the issue is that when I click on one submenu item it expands fine.  Then when I click on another submenu item, the previous one stays open and the new clicked on also opens and so forth.  The only way to collaps the is to click on them again.  Looking at the abvove javascript, what am I missing to collapse the other submenu items when I expand on a new one?

Here is a sample:

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

Comment: Can you show the whole html. I mean the `grandparent` item you are addressing (parent of `<li class="dropdown-submenu submenu">`).

Comment: The class name in your HTML is submenu and in your script it's sub-menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
```

to

```
grandparent.find("li .submenu:visible").not(current).hide();
```

and it worked for me. Here's a working jsFiddle with most of the styling stripped away - http://jsfiddle.net/3xz39smb/